# Show that $\mu(x)$ is a integrating factor

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, integrating-factor

> Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a simply connected domain.
> Furthermore, let $f, g: D \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two
> continuously differentiable functions with $
>  \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(x, y)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
>  h(x, y)}{h(x, y)}=f(x) $ for all $(x, y) \in D$.
>
> 1. show that $ \mu(x):=\exp \left(\int f(x) \mathrm{d} x\right) $ is an integrating factor.
> 2. under what conditions is there an integrating factor that depends only on y and what is it?

The theory says that for an ordinary differential equation of the form $p(x, y)+q(x, y) \frac{\mathrm{dy}}{\mathrm{dx}}=0$, which does not fulfil the integrability condition $\frac{\partial p}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}$, there is (under certain regularity conditions) always a zero-free continuously differentiable function $\mu(x, y) \neq 0$ such that
$$
\mu(x, y) p(x, y)+\mu(x, y) q(x, y) \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{~d} x}=0
$$
becomes an exact differential equation.

**Edit 2 (answer from Salamo):**

So I have to show the reverse direction of the following:
$$
\frac{\partial(\mu g)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial(\mu h)}{\partial x}
$$
also with product rule
$$
\mu \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}+g \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}=\mu \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}+h \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}
$$
or slightly rewritten
$$
\frac{1}{\mu}\left(h \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x}-g \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y}\right)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} .
$$

If $\mu$ now only depends on $x$, this becomes
$$
\frac{1}{\mu} \frac{d \mu}{d x}=\frac{1}{h}\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)=: f(x) .
$$

Due to $\frac{1}{\mu} \frac{d \mu}{d x}=\frac{d}{d x} \log \mu$, it then follows that $\mu(x)=\exp \left(\int f(x) d x\right)$.

But now it is still unclear to me how to solve the second part of the problem regarding the y?

Comment: you have to show $\mu$ multiplied to your equation, it becomes exact.

Comment: Is my edit consider correctly???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Substituting $\mu(x)=\exp\left(\int f(x)\, dx\right)$ into
$$
\frac{\partial (\mu g)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (\mu h)}{\partial x}\tag{1}
$$
yields $f(x)h(x,y)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}$ which holds by definition of your $f(x)$. Thus, $\mu(x)$ is an integrating factor for your differential equation.

As to the second task, note that $(1)$ is equivalent to
$$
\frac{1}{\mu(x,y)}\left(h(x,y)\frac{\partial\mu(x,y)}{\partial x}-g(x,y)\frac{\partial\mu(x,y)}{\partial y}\right)=\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y}-\frac{\partial h(x,y)}{\partial x}\tag{2}.
$$
Assume that $\mu=\mu(y)$. This will give you a right-hand side which depends on $y$ only, call it $q(y)$. Then, $\mu(y):=\exp\left(\int q(y)\, dy\right)$ is your integrating factor.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I've edited something again - so I have just to show the reverse direction (i.e. $\mu(x)=\exp \left(\int f(x) d x\right)$)

Comment: The second part is now clear to me - thanks :)

Comment: As to the second part you just have to determine the explicit form of $q(y)$.